# Maximizing profit when demand is a power function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, finance

I'm doing [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/wharton-quantitative-modeling) on mathematical modeling. In [lecture 2 on optimization](https://www.coursera.org/learn/wharton-quantitative-modeling/lecture/otaRi/2-5-optimization) the following optimization problem is described.
The power demand function is 
$$ q = a * p^{b} $$
with quantity sold $q$, $a = 60 000$, price $p$ and $b = -2.5$ (called the price elasticity). The profit can be calculated by 
$$ profit = p*q-c*q $$
with cost per unit $c$. The question asked is then: *if the cost $c = 2$ per unit, at what price is the profit maximized?*

In the lecture, the problem is first solved using a brute force approach (i.e. calculating the profit for a number of different prices). Then, the optimal prize, obtained through calculus is given, which is
$$price_{opt} = \frac{c*b}{1+b} $$
with $b$ the exponent in the power demand function (i.e. -2.5). This is done by derivation of the price function with respect to price $p$ and checking when the derivative is equal to 0. The answer obtained using this function is $price_{opt} = 3.33$.

**My question is how to arrive at the given solution. It's not explained in the lecture, as it is not the focus of that course.** I've tried expressing p in terms of q giving $p = q^{-b} * a^b$ and then plugging that into the formula for profit and deriving that, but this becomes rather complex and not at all like the answer given. Furthermore, when I search for this online I can only find examples with linear demand functions (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703600/am-i-doing-something-wrong-here-maximization-of-profit-problem?rq=1)).
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the profit which is a function of the price $p$. Note that
$$
P(p)=q(p-c)=ap^b(p-c)=ap^{b+1}-acp^b; \quad (p>0).
$$
Then
$$
P'(p)=p^{b-1}(a(b+1)p-acb)\tag{1}
$$
so that
$$
P'(p)=0\iff a(b+1)p=acb\iff p=\frac{cb}{b+1}.
$$
To check that a maximum actually occurs at this point use the first derivative test. Observe that from (1) if $p<\frac{cb}{b+1}$, $P'(p)>0$ and if $p>\frac{cb}{b+1}$, $P'(p)<0$. Hence
$$
p_{\text{optimal}}=\frac{cb}{b+1}.
$$